# Export trusted certificates from jks file to .pem and get the private key as .pem

Tags: ssl, https, keystore

I have a 'test6r.jks' file which conatins 1 private key and 3 trusted certs I would like to get 3 crts as public.pem and private key as private.pem

```
keytool -list -keystore test6r.jks 
Enter keystore password:  

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 4 entries

symantecclass3secureserverca-g4, Mar 25, 2015, trustedCertEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1):
FF:67:36:7C:5C:D4:DE:4A:E1:8B:CC:E1:D7:0F:DA:BD:7C:86:61:35

verisignsvrg3, Mar 25, 2015, trustedCertEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 5D:EB:8F:33:9E:26:4C:19:F6:68:6F:5F:8F:32:B5:4A:4C:46:B4:76

verisignroot, Mar 25, 2015, trustedCertEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 4E:B6:D5:78:49:9B:1C:CF:5F:58:1E:AD:56:BE:3D:9B:67:44:A5:E5

test6r, Nov 9, 2016, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): C9:E4:A7:CB:A1:31:89:DA:EE:59:A3:50:CD:0E:04:7D:36:6B:23:CB
```

How do I export trusted certificates from jks file to .pem and get the private key as .pem?

Comment: Convert the Java keystore file to PKCS#12 format with the `keytool` and then use `OpenSSL.exe` on it to extract the certs and private key. There are several answers here showing how.

Comment: I am able do that for private key. but how to get public cert? there are 3 trustedCertEntries